# pygame: drawing order for sprite group with sprite.RenderPlain

Tags: python, python-2.7, sprite, pygame

I've got a sprite group which needs to be drawn in a certain order so its sprites overlap as they should.

However even when sorting the group using operator module function (sorted(self.sprites, key=attrgetter('y','x')) the order is wrong.

How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straightforwardly, [you can't](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#Group.draw):

> The Group does not keep sprites in any order, so the draw order is
>   arbitrary.

Use an [OrderedUpdates group](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates) instead:

> This class derives from `pygame.sprite.RenderUpdates` - Group class that
>   tracks dirty updates. It maintains the order in which the Sprites were
>   added to the Group for rendering. This makes adding and removing
>   Sprites from the Group a little slower than regular Groups.

Alternatively, you can keep different 'layers' of sprites in different groups, keeping the order of *groups* correct.