# pygame in depth visual animation

Tags: python, pygame

I have been trying to create a simple game in python by using pygame package. It is a basketball 2 player game and I wanted to know if there is a way in order to animate the player to be printed above the basket when he is before it and to be printed under it when he is behind the basket. I know that the order of the images displayed is organised by the order of the written code in the editor so I wanted to know how to change that temporarily depending on the X coordinate.

---

[image: Two figures]

---

For example like in the png above where in the left object the sphere is above the square and in the right object the square is above the circle

in this example the circle is the immoveable object(basket) and the square is the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case, you want a sprite system where everything you draw has a "depth" attribute, and [you draw things in that sorted order, from back to front, i.e. Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Painter%27s_algorithm).

There's a slightly related question and answer over at [pygame: drawing order for sprite group with sprite.RenderPlain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675741/pygame-drawing-order-for-sprite-group-with-sprite-renderplain).

If you're not using sprites or such, you can of course do this manually, but for a more complex game, I think this'll end up very tedious and spaghetti-y:

```
if player_y < basket_y:
   draw_basket()
   draw_player()
else:
   draw_basket()
   draw_player()
```